# InkCanvas. Сериализовать, десериализовать и сохранить картинку

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Использую для рисования InkCanvas.
Задачи:

1) Произвести сериализацию коллекций Children и Strokes,чтобы их можно было сохранить в формате XML.

2) Произвести десериализацию полученного файла.

3) Создать файл jpg или png отображающий все элементы коллекций Strokes.

Comment: Используйте MVVM. Сериализация — это сфера ответственности модели, а не представления.

Comment: Это очевидно не ответ.

Comment: Ну да, это комментарий.

Comment: К сожалению, бесполезный.